# {no_results} doesn't work if channel:entries uses category="" as parameter

Tags: channel-entries, categories

I have a very strange issue. When using the first EE channel:entries code my no_results tag works, but when using the exact same channel:entries tag together with the category="" parameter the no_results tag doesn't work. Any ideas?

The {last_segment_category_id} variable being empty, of course.

Works:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" dynamic="no" disable="pagination|member_data"}
{if no_results}
<i>No results...</i>
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Doesn't work:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" category="{last_segment_category_id}" dynamic="no" disable="pagination|member_data"}
{if no_results}
<i>No results...</i>
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the require_entry="yes" parameter? The issue is it's picking up something in the category parameter due to {last_segment_category_id}. What happens if you hard code a category id?

Comment: The require_entry="yes" didn't change anything and if I hard-code an category_id="123" that doesn't exist there's no entries in the loop but the no_results tag doesn't work either. It doesn't output any entries, but it doesn't recognize there's no result either?

Comment: Did you figure out the answer? i'm having the same thing here.

Comment: No. I believe this is as excepted by the tag I'm afraid. I would consider this a bug but I don't know :)

Comment: Submit this as a bug: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work around you can do to get the same desired results:

```
{exp:query limit="1 sql="SELECT entry_id FROM `exp_category_posts` WHERE cat_id = '{last_segment_category_id}"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" category="{last_segment_category_id}" dynamic="no" disable="pagination|member_data"}
       <h1>Title</h1>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
    {if no_results}
       No Results....
    {/if}
{/exp:query}
```

What i'm doing here is querying the database to check to see if any entry_ids exist connected to a given category. If so, it will parse the expression engine tags, if not it will display the exp:query no results content.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported to EllisLab as a bug. It is not working as it should. https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21106